# GCM - Messages not always stored on server or arriving after reboot

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Im trying to implement push notifications on my client.
What I basically do from my server is sending a POST message with the appropriate parameters.
Whenever I POST, I get success 1 in the details.
I tried using [this tutorial](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/android-push-notification-cloud-to-device-messaging/)

I notice two important issues and I encountered them in other implementations I tried before:
1. If I reboot the phone, I wont get notifications till I Open the application again
2. Any notifications in the meanwhile arent sent to my client. My server gets success: 1 so It cant tell if it needs to resend it, and also as far as Google describe the feature, GCM servers should handle it, so my server just needs to send and forget.
The only situation where it works is if I open the app and then, whenever its in the background or closed completely (but not trough task manager), it will receive my notifications instantly.

What do I need to do in order to solve those two issues I mentioned?

Edit:
Even tough the link contains the entire code, here is my BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

The intentService, used for the actual processing:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

The receiver part in my manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.example.demoapp.app.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.demoapp.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: There's something wrong in your BroadcastReceiver.  Post code please.

Comment: @user1199931 sure, it exists in the link (which is actually taken 1:1 from google's developers site) but I updated the main post

Comment: Code looks ok, you put the receiver in manifest file?

Comment: yes, my manifest contains the receiver. I updated the main post to include it